# Angular custom search starting from first letter

Tags: angularjs, search

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/s08nypfd/) is what I am looking for. I got this example from one of the stackoverflow post.

However, In my case I need to search using first letter of name.

Here is the json file.

```
var userList = {
    "user":[
      {
        "image": "adam.jpg",
        "name": "Sanket Jain",
        "email": "SanketJain@gmail.com",
        "phone" : "9850987634"
      },
      {
        "image": "ben.png",
        "name": "Amar Patil",
        "email": "amarPatil@gmail.com",
        "phone" : "9951983334"
      },
      {
        "image": "max.png",
        "name": "Prasad Kulkarni",
        "email": "prasadKulkarni@gmail.com",
        "phone" : "9253454634"
      },
      {
        "image": "mike.png",
        "name": "Tushar Salvi",
        "email": "tusharSalvi@gmail.com",
        "phone" : "9450987634"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need case sensitive:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).filter('myfilter', function(){
return function(input, text){
    return input.filter(function(item){
        return item.name.startsWith(text);
    });
};
});
```

If you need case insensitive:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).filter('myfilter', function(){
return function(input, text){
    return input.filter(function(item){
    var lowerStr = (item.name + "").toLowerCase();
        return lowerStr.indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) === 0;
    });
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `myfilter` function, instead of this line

```
return item.startsWith(text);
```

try to write this one

```
return item.name.startsWith(text);
```

Comment: My solution is case sensitive. I you want insensitive, then solution provided by zamarrowski will do the job.